# Why does a recursive function do the last part first?

Tags: java, recursion

I indicate the base case as `emptySpace=0` and the else if condition has the base case as `star=0`. I was expecting that the program would print the spaces first after it prints the stars but the opposite situation happens. Shouldn't it print the spaces first then stars?

```
public static void displayStarss(int emptySpace, int star) {
    if (emptySpace != 0) {
         displayStarss(emptySpace - 1, star);
         System.out.print(" ");
    } else if (star != 0) {
        displayStarss(emptySpace, star - 1);
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayStarss(3, 3);
}
```

Comment: How do you call it? Pick low numbers and "play computer" with a pencil and paper, or step through the code.

Comment: Also, watch what happens if you move the recursive call one line lower in each branch and have the print statement before you step into the recursion.

Answer (score 2):

It follows your orders on which order it should do things:

```
displayStarss(3, 3);
-> displayStarss(2, 3);
-> -> displayStarss(1, 3);
-> -> -> displayStarss(0, 3);
-> -> -> -> displayStarss(0, 2);
-> -> -> -> -> displayStarss(0, 1);
-> -> -> -> -> -> displayStarss(0, 0);
-> -> -> -> -> System.out.print("*");
-> -> -> -> System.out.print("*");
-> -> -> System.out.print("*");
-> -> System.out.print(" ");
-> System.out.print(" ");
System.out.print(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us say we call this with parameters 2 for both `emptySpace` and `stars`

The call goes as

```
displayStarss(2, 2) //called from main (starting point)

displayStarss(1, 2) //called from if
displayStarss(0, 2) //called from if

displayStarss(0, 1) //called from else if
displayStarss(0, 0) //called from else if
<<recursion ends here and it returns>>
```

Now, if you *unwind* the above call sequence, it can be seen that it must print the stars before the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't.  It may do it in order.  It all depends on how you structure the program.
Consider the following:

```java
   public static void count(int n) {
      // when n == 0 start the return process
      if (n == 0) {
         return;
      }
      // Nothing has been printed yet
      // Call count again, this time with one less than n.
      count(n - 1);
      // all returns will end up here, restoring each previously
      // altered value of n.
      System.out.println(n);
   }
```

This program will print all the values from `1` to `n`.  That is because the print statement is `after` the recursive call to `count`, each time specifying one less than `n`.  So the call stack keeps these values and returns them in order.

If you move the print statement right before the call to `count`, the values will be printed from `n` to `1`. In this latter case, the returns still happen, but nothing is being done so they just return in succession until the method returns to the original caller.